# What type of plug is this?

Tags: identification, connector, plug, power-connector

I'm seeking to buy this type of plug but can't find it anywhere. I tried asking at my local electronics shops, googled the images and consulted the data sheet of the appliance it came with. (12V input on an [Indel B fridge](https://www.indelb.com/products/automotive/travel_box/tb46_steel).)

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I didn't know the answer, but I want to comment that you've posted a *very good* set of pictures for identifying a connector.  Anyone browsing this question -- *that's* how you do it!

Comment: @TimWescott Your comment - ten votes, this question five.  C'mon folks - this is a great question.  If you agree with Tim, give OP some credit here.

Comment: Type "car fridge power cord" in the amazon search box. I had same issue with a different brand of portable cooler...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That looks like a C11 plug.  Might be hard to find from a legitimate source since it was withdrawn from the IEC 60320 standard.

Comment: *"...it was withdrawn from the IEC 60320 standard."* And has been for over twenty years.  The oldest revision of 60320 I could find was the 2001 revision (2.0) and C11/12 were not included there.  It would be a challenge even to find new old stock of these.  Salvage is probably your best bet, or just rewiring the appliance to accept a different connector.

Comment: As suggested, modifying the appliance would be easy. A connector like this would bring you back to current standards... https://www.amazon.com/Panel-Adapter-Connector-Socket-MXR/dp/B07DCXKNXQ/ref=sr_1_12?keywords=iec+c11&qid=1639484994&sr=8-12

Comment: @GTElectronics the OP says it's a 12 V power input - that wouldn't be a correct use of a C13/C14 pair surely, as it would risk someone connecting mains voltage to it.

Answer (score 6):

C11 connector that pairs with a C12 inlet.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple brands of DC-powered portable refrigerator/coolers on Amazon use this connector type. You can find replacement DC cords and AC Power adapters by searching for them on Amazon.